# Flutter - Add Image to BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to add an Image widget or Text widget to one of the BottomNavigationBarItem, as shown in the bellow image.

But it seems that all icons placeholder have the same width, and I don't know how to make the center "icon" (Book Now) wider.

I am tryind to implement a persistente Scaffold bottomNavigationBar, and from all articles that I have read, almost all use the BottomNavigationBar and the **BottomNavigationBarItem**

[image]

I am getting this instead:

[image]
[image]

My code is:

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
                showSelectedLabels: false,
                showUnselectedLabels: false,
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                          Feather.home,
                          color: kGoodLightGray,
                        ),
              title: Container(height: 0,),
              activeIcon: Icon(
                          Feather.home,
                          color: kGoodPurple,
                        ),
                      ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Feather.search,
                      color: kGoodLightGray,
                    ),
                    title: Container(height: 0,),
                    activeIcon: Icon(
                      Feather.search,
                      color: kGoodPurple,
                    ),
                  ),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Text('Book Now', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),),
              title: Container(height: 0,),
                      activeIcon: Icon(
                FontAwesome.calendar,
                        color: kGoodPurple,
                      ),
                    ),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(
                        EvilIcons.calendar,
                        color: kGoodLightGray,
                        size: 36,
                      ),
              title: Container(height: 0,),
                      activeIcon: Icon(
                        EvilIcons.calendar,
                        color: kGoodPurple,
                        size: 36,
                      ),
                    ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      EvilIcons.user,
                      color: kGoodLightGray,
                      size: 36,
                    ),
                    title: Container(height: 0,),
                    activeIcon: Icon(
                      EvilIcons.user,
                      color: kGoodPurple,
                      size: 36,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ],
                  onTap: (index) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            _buildOffstageNavigator(0),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(1),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(2),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

While `BottomNavigationBar` is a great widget when you want standard behaviour, in your case I would go for something that gives you more control. Instead of forcing it to behave the way you want, you can add a `BottomAppBar` with a `Row` widget. You can easily extend it to show different icons reflecting active / non-active states. Try the following simple code and adjust is as you like:

```
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
              color: Colors.lightGreen[100],
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text('Book now'),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ))),
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I like your ideia, but I am not being able to navigate between screens, I will try more and let you know.

Comment: For example you can use an [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html) and set the `index` in the `onPressed` methods with setState() to the appropriate value. This way you can also add different style to the IconButtons when selected.

Comment: But of course you can use the `Navigator` class as well, for example `popAndPushNamed`.